# Adding an int[] to a dynamic array such as Array List

Tags: java, arrays, list, integer, int

As the heading suggests I am looking for a way to add arrays filled with information that can be x length to a growing array list.

I have done my research and it seems that if I choose to put the array into a array list then it will be individual values of the original array in a list, where as I want the entire array to the array list.

I know this is complicating to understand so see below.

So say we go through the first loop of my application and produces the following arrays

```
{1,2,3,4}
{5,6,7,8}
```

if I put this into an Arraylist it will be the following

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

however I want it as the following

```
{1,2,3,4}
{5,6,7,8}
and so on...
```

The reason is because I want to store arrays in order for my programme to test against values of each array stored whilst looping through.

Is this possible in Java? I am sure it is but I am just missing something!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the number of arrays produced in advance, you can use a 2-dimensional array.

**Example**

```
int[] first = {1,2,3,4};
int[] second = {5,6,7,8};
int[][] all = new int[2][];
all[0] = first;
all[1] = second;
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(all));
```

**Output**

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

Otherwise, just use an `ArrayList<int[]>`, but that's ugly - see below.

**Example**

```
int[] first = {1,2,3,4};
int[] second = {5,6,7,8};
List<int[]> all = new ArrayList<int[]>();
all.add(first);
all.add(second);
// no nice String representation here as Arrays.toString not explicitly invoked
System.out.println(all);
```

**Output**

```
[[I@466e466e, [I@46734673]
```

Final and best solution, use an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>`.

**Example**

```
// cannot use primitive arrays in this context without tedious iteration
Integer[] first = {1,2,3,4};
Integer[] second = {5,6,7,8};
List<List<Integer>> all = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
all.add(Arrays.asList(first));
all.add(Arrays.asList(second));
System.out.println(all);
```

**Output**

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

**Final note**

You might also want to look into the `Map` [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), see whether a `Map<Object, List<Integer>>` or even simply a `Map<Integer, Integer>` might fit your data requirements better.

Comment: No I dont think thats the solution to the problem, it could go through and produce x amount of arrays... It was my reason why I opted for a list array as it will need to be dynamic.

Comment: As for the ArrayList<int[]> what will be the difference? it will still just list, no?

yes I believe the list within a list is the best solution so far, I will wait and see other peoples views but will go with that one.

Answer (score 0):

Why not having a list of lists? It's easy enough to convert array into list and then you would have:

`List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();`

EDIT:

Lets assume you have an array called `myArray`. You add to list declared above as follow:

`list.add(Arrays.asList(myArray));`

do that with several arrays and you will have a List that contains several separate lists such as:

{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, ... and so on

Comment: ok, sorry I am new to java. What will be the output say I add two arrays to this, would it be like what I have in my question or just a list which has a internal list? 

so we add {1,2} and {3,4}
'
- 1
  2
- 3
  4
'
is that right?

Comment: First of all you wouldn't be adding arrays but lists. And if you add several lists into one list you will have a list that contains several lists. Give me 2 minutes and check my edit.